# Why does my form widget render on every request EXCEPT for the first request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a problem with a recaptcha widget that I am trying to render on my new.html.haml file. When I click on a link to take me to

```
localhost:3000/forums/:id/topics/new
```

I am met with a form that I've created on the new.html.haml page with all the fields detailed except for a recaptcha widget, which I need rendered.

When I refresh the new.html.haml page the recaptcha widget is rendered including all subsequent requests and I am able to see the widget on the web page. Why does this happen? I've never encountered an error like this before and I don't even know where to start looking. In my development.log file, I notice that when I send the first GET request to new.html.haml I see that no GET request is made to any assets in my rails app. Here is a picture below illustrating my point:

[image]

When I click the refresh page, I have the exact same output as the picture below with the exception that a series of GET requests will start to grap everything in my assets folder. On the refresh request, I will see a series of lines like the one below:

```
Started GET "/assets/jquery.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-22 12:45:11 -0500
```

I'm assuming that this is the problem, but where do I go from here? I've read about the asset pipeline but I didn't find anything that seemed relevant to this problem. Is this a caching problem? What other avenue can I explore to narrow this down? Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Most likely it's because of turbolinks. Read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27866331/date-picker-does-not-show-in-rails-unless-refresh/27866701#27866701

Comment: Hey BroiSatse, thanks for illuminating what was the problem. The turbolinks gem was the problem and I got it solved with your help although I didn't have to write any javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to BroiSatse, I discovered that the problem was indeed turbolinks. To solve the problem all I needed to do was to extract the new_path from turbolinks like so:

```
<a href="/">Home (via Turbolinks)</a>
  <div id="some-div" data-no-turbolink>
<a href="/">Home (without Turbolinks)</a>
</div>
```

More information can be found on the turbolinks github page: [Turbolinks docs](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks)